# Add custom product to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, woothemes

I am currently developing an interface that allows you to customize a product. I am implementing on Wordpress, but I need to generate an order after you finish the customization process. So it is necessary that the data is added as a product in the shopping cart WooCommerce. Is that possible? What would be the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements i assume a following scenario

For example you have a site which which sells printed Tshirts.
The flow of this example site is that a user comes selects a tshirt, customizes the tshirt product say by adding Tshirt's color, Image on tshirt and Tshirt's size.

These customization added by the customer at the frontend on product page or cart can be stored in post meta for that order.

So if your case is some what like this then Yes this is possible.

And you can use the following links which will help you to achieve your goal.

[How to Add Custom Data to WooCommerce Order](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order/)

and

[Custom WooCommerce Order Meta](http://yourplatoon.com/blog/custom-woocommerce-order-meta/)

Let me know if this solution works for you.